# Splitting a string loaded to the server using php code

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

Me again, I build up a string that I store on a server with this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < GlobalVarsScript.gins.Count; i++)
{
    ginString += GlobalVarsScript.gins[i]._ginName + "\n" +
    GlobalVarsScript.gins[i]._country + "\n" + 
    GlobalVarsScript.gins[i]._abv + "\n" +
    GlobalVarsScript.gins[i]._price + "\n" +
    GlobalVarsScript.gins[i]._votes + "\n" +
    GlobalVarsScript.gins[i]._stars + "\n \n";
}
```

And the output is as I expected -

[image]

But when loaded onto the sever with this C# and .php code

```
url = "http://www.thelabmultiplayer.com/ewExternalFiles/RewriteGinString.php?txt=" + WWW.EscapeURL(ginString);


<?php
    $txtcontent = $_REQUEST['txt'];
    $fp = fopen("GinStringFile.txt", w);
    fwrite($fp, $txtcontent);
    // take out next line when App is complete
    echo $fp;
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

It reads like this:

[image]

Can I load it to the sever so it reads like the first one by splitting the string at the \n points? Thanks.

EDIT - added php code ..

```
<?php
$file = fopen("GinStringFile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread(nl2br($file),filesize("GinStringFile.txt"));
fclose($file);
```

?>

Comment: Did you try using [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)?

Comment: Hi, If I add the php code I've added to my question above I get no output ..

Comment: Use `nl2br` on the file contents before you echo it and not on the file resource. Also you can probably just use `file_get_contents` instead of `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose`.